# Show that a group of order 3 is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

To begin, yes its a duplicate but none of the answers ive seen were intuitive for me. The difinition of a cyclic group is that $\exists a\in G(G=\{a^{n}|n\in \mathbb{Z}\})$. So I thought of starting with the assumption that there is an element in G and then prove that $(G=\{a^{n}|n\in \mathbb{Z}\})$.

Suppose G is a group of order 3.

let $a_{0}\in G$ and let $\varsigma=\{(a_{0})^{n}|n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Let $a^{k}\in G$ for some integer k. Let $k=nq+r$ then $a^{k}=a^{nq}a^{r}$ for $0\le r\lt n$

Let $a^{m}\in \varsigma$ for some integer $m$ and $m=nq+r$, then $a^{m}=a^{nq}a^{r}$ for $0\le r\lt n$

It doesnt seem right to say that $a^{k}=a^{m}$ without further justification. But im not sure exactly how to justify it. Was all my logic even consistent up to that point? Were does the assumption that G is of order 3 come into the proof?

Comment: So.. you want to prove that a group is cyclic, and in order to do that, you will *assume* that it is cyclic and then... what? Why would you *start* by assuming there is an element $a$ such that $G=\{x^k\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$? Also. don't just say "all the [duplicate] ones I've seen are unintuitive". Point to **specific** duplicates and state **explicitly** what is the problem you have with them. Finally, a proof need not be "intuitive". It only needs to be correct.

Comment: There's really only one possible Cayley table for a group of order $3$, and guess what?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Did i really assume it was cyclic? I thought all i stated was that theres an element a in G and then defined a set with it. In my view i never said the set was equal to G. To adress your second comment, i mispoke then what i meant was that i dont understand them. So I wanted to write my own proof. But even then it is reasonable that it is expected of me to point to specific duplicates.

Comment: @Randall I know, ive seen that approach but i wanted to try a proof my own way for the sake of it.

Comment: "I thought I would start with the assumption that there is such an element." Since what you said is "a group $G$ is cyclic if there exists an element $a$ such that $G=\{a^k\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$", "such an element" *means* "an element $a$ such that $G=\{ a^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$". That's the only possible interpretation to "I will assume there is such an element."

Comment: I saw the error. But what i meant to say was let $a_{0}\in G$ and let $\varsigma=\{(a_{0})^{n} | n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: You provide zero context. What do you know about groups? What results do you have on hand? Lagrange? Cauchy? Anything other than the definition? That's why **context** is necessary, and why you should tell us what you don't understand about the myriad of proofs that are available on the internet and on this very site.

Comment: I wanted to prove it with just the givens. with the definition of a cyclic group and using the division theorem. I did come  to a conclusion that an arbitrary element of G is in $\varsigma$ and vice versa, but i was not sure if it needs further justification and in addition how can we use the given that G has order 3, since it never came up in the proof and i wasnt sure what to do with that fact

Comment: By "the division theorem" you mean the division algorithm? The reason the fact that $G$ has order $3$ "never came up" is because you didn't prove anything. Because you are never trying to see if an *arbitrary* element $x\in G$ will like in $\{a_0^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, and you never try to figure out what that set actually is. So, it is unsurprising that your assumptions are never used, when you never do any argument. You also never say who $n$ is when you apply the Division Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unfamiliar with Lagrange's theorem that says the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group and you don't want to use a multiplication table we can do this from first principles.

Let $G$ be a group of order three and let $x\in G$ with $x$ not equal to the identity $e\in G$. Consider $$x, x^2,\text{ and }x^3$$ By the pigeonhole principle, one of these must be equal to the identity $e$. By assumption, this cannot be $x$ so either $x^2=e$ or $x^3=e$. If we can show that $x^2\ne e$ then $x^3=e$ and we are done.

If $x^2=e$ then $x,x^2,x^3=x,e,x$ which gives us only two elements of $G$ so we have another element $y\ne e\in G$.

Consider $xy$. This product must equal either $x$, $y$ or $e$. $$xy=x\implies xy=xe\implies y= e\text{ which is a contradiction}\\xy=y\implies xy=ey\implies x=e\text{ also a contradiction}\\xy=e\implies xy=xx\implies y=x$$ which is also a contradiction so if $x^2=e$, there is no way to define $xy$.

Therefore, $x^3=1$ and $G=\{e, x, x^2\}$ which is cyclic.

Answer (score -2):

Pf: Take $G$ to be a group of order $3$, then by def $G$ must contain an identity $e$, an element $a$, and the inverse of $a$. Then the group table is as follows:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{$e$} & \text{$a$} & \text{$a^{-1}$} \\ \hline
\text{$e$} & \text{$e$} & \text{$a$} & \text{$a^{-1}$} \\ \hline
\text{$a$} & \text{$a$} & \text{$a^2$} & \text{$e$} \\ \hline
\text{$a^{-1}$} & \text{$a^{-1}$} & \text{$e$} & \text{$(a^{-1})^2$} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

This makes it clear that $a^2=a^{-1}$ and $(a^{-1})^2=a$ as $a \ne a^{-1} \ne e$ yielding that $e = a^0,$ $ a = a^1,$ $a^2 = a^{-1}$ thus $G$ is cyclic.